# Data relationships take too much space

Tags: c#, sqlite, protobuf-net, data-driven

I am building a moddable game and I ran into data size problem where game takes too much hard drive space. I have ObjectData table that represents these things:

- unique object ID
- object id (for editor and in-game commands)
- list of other objects (IDs) that made copy of template object
- list of other objects (IDs) that uses this template object

IDs of other objects are needed because of cases where template object is deleted and game editor needs to remove all references to it from other objects. So if decide to delete some inventory item template it will remove itself from characters that are using it.

I got this system up and running, but when I tried to test it with many relationships between different data, my system returned a file about 2Gb of size.

I tried to compress it, I tried to serialize it with binary serializer, but my data is still huge.

What could I try next? Of course I could rebuild those relationships between data on the run, when the game is running or game editor is booting up, but if I would have a lot of objects that process would take a lot of time.

Comment: Have you made sure to use appropriate types - for example, not using a 32-bit int where a byte would work?

Comment: Can you maybe put some commas or something in your second paragraph?  It's hard to see where one item ends and the next begins.

Comment: @DM Sorry, I copied my question from other forum and I didn't noticed that formatting was gone.

Comment: *Realtionships*  take almost no space, and the binary formatter just serializes, it is not a compressor.  Compressing the disk space would be a trade off - slower load and save times but less space.  Hard to tell what you are really asking - a bunch of IDs as shown wont take much space either.

Comment: @DM For IDs I use GUID, so I realize that's why it takes so much space. But how can byte work in this case if I have a lot  of template objects that need to have unique ids?

Comment: @martynaspikunas Well, OK, byte won't work.  But how many objects are you dealing with?  Perhaps a 32-bit integer would work.  That's a quarter of the space of a GUID.  It might not be a final solution, but surely 500 MB is better than 2 GB.

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah, IDs itself don't take a lot of space, but each game object creates ObjectData instance that contains a list of other objects that are copies of a original one. That's where space usage increases rapidly, because one template object can have even tens of thousands of copies.

Comment: Yeah, those last 2 bullets seem redundant if needed at all.  Rather than 2 long lists, you could have one which also has a qualifier as to what type it is.  Then rather than keep the list at all, when something is removed, you could use linq to find those other things using a specific Id.

Comment: Thing is that I can't keep all my data in memory, so I tried storing it in database. Without global list checking those relationships on deletion or loading can take some time.

Comment: If it is in a DB you dont need to load it to delete it

Comment: @Plutonix Haven't thought about that. Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged this protobuf-net (my bat-signal) - is there some specific protobuf-net consideration you're interested in? have you *tried* using protobuf-net? Have you done the "back of an envelope" math to figure out the minimum **required** data to store this data? Yes, `BinaryFormatter` tends to be relatively expensive (because of the amount of metadata and name data) - I'd be more than happy to give an example of doing the same with protobuf-net, but there's no model here for me to illustrate against...

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi, Marc! I am using protobuf-net and its great. Thanks. The problem is that in my new project I would like to keep my data in one file. Protobuf-net works great at that for me, but my data file is getting bigger and I can't keep it in memory all the time, so I need to unload it. Protobuf-net would be ideal if I could read specific parts without loading everything into memory (streaming I guess) and if I could update serialized file without re-serializing all the data again.

Comment: @martynaspikunas well, the first of those is *possible but not convenient* - you'd need a good reason to do it; the second is simply not really a feature of the protobuf data format unless you're only talking about a single object - see here for more context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883721/update-existing-field-in-listt-and-re-save-into-same-protobuf-net-file

Comment: @MarcGravell Looks like that it might just work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @martynaspikunas note the severe restrictions around "repeated" data (including lists, arrays and maps/dictionaries); that approach only works for objects with a single non-repeated path to them